# What is the netting dressing for a deep cut called?

Tags: nouns, medical

When there is a deep cut we use some sort of netting dressing to pull the sides of the skin together so the healing process is shorter and leaves no or smaller scars.

What do we call it? Is it just "netting dressing" or is there any special name for it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steri-Strip

Comment: Or butterfly stitches.

Comment: Can you provide a photograph or a link? What you describe sounds like *[butterfly bandages](http://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/articles/health_tools/bandaging_from_head_to_toe_slideshow/webmd_rm_photo_of_bandage_on_open_cut.jpg)*.

Comment: This is still unclear. 'netting dressing' doesn't correspond well to anything in English, but evokes things which are inconsistent with your description. Are you looking for a cover of the wound or something to press down on it to stop bleeding?  (these would be bandages or gauze that often have a mesh construction to sop up blood). Or are you looking for holding the two sides of the flesh together so they'll heal will less scarring? (these are stitches, that are sewn through the flesh like shoe-laces to hold things together)

Comment: Yeah, probably you're looking for "gauze", though there are dozens of different types of bandages and wound closures.

Comment: Choster, here it goes:

http://parapais.com/ai-os-meus-pontos-sao-mesmo-desconfortaveis-qual-a-melhor-forma-de-abrandar-a-dor/

Answer (score 4):

You may be referring to "Gauze"

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gauze?s=t

> 2. a surgical dressing of loosely woven cotton.

Comment: Thank you Marv, but looking the comments above I figured out stitches is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are different products that fit that description. Searching for *tubular bandage* or *tubular dressing* will turn up a number of them, so those are two reasonably generic terms that you could use. Some examples of specific products are:

- Curad Hold Tite Tubular Stretch Bandage: [image: Curad Hold Tite Tubular Stretch Bandage]
- Surgilast Tubular Elastic Dressing Retainer [image: Surgilast Tubular Elastic Dressing Retainer]
- Tubular Gauze [image: Tubular Gauze]

These all fit the "netting" part of your description, but I'm not sure that their primary purpose is to hold the edges of wounds together; (I'm not a doctor, but...) they seem to be used more to hold other dressing components in place. From personal experience as a patient, products used to hold skin together tend to be more adhesive or mechanical, such as butterflies, Steri-strips, glue, sutures, and staples. None of these bear much resemblance to netting, so I don't think they're what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, but stitches is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

*Mesh dressing* may be the term you are looking for; see these [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mesh+dressing%22&num=100&safe=off&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS577US577&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=r_yQVMSbCo_ggwTQnICQBA&ved=0CGoQsAQ&biw=1846&bih=995) images.